# How to manually run Windows Update for Windows 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

I'd like to manually run windows update without accessing the windows update web site. Could you give me a hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start->Run

```
wuauclt.exe /detectnow
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately that didn't work. I run that command and nothing happens (no error, no message, just nothing)

Comment: There's a script we have run that I think uses this command...it doesn't give any visual feedback unless the updates show up in the system tray. The Windows Update function was designed by idgits, I think...very little feedback.

Comment: There's a logfile kept to it's activities but I can't remember where off the top of my head. You'd have to look at the process monitor to se if wuauclt is running, then google for the windows update logfile that will give you feedback.

Comment: @Timmy: Are you sure that you have the latest (required) updates installed? They require a new Windows Installer to get updates, you get this via the Windows Update website at first launch.

Comment: I know nothing :), it's not my machine. Since it's a client server I won't play with it. I think I could handle it in another way. Thanks man.

Answer (score 7):

[Microsoft has a script to search, download, and install Windows Updates from the command line.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387102%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Absolutely brilliant resource, @Chris S!

Comment: great link, I hadn't seen anyone at Microsoft put out sample com MSupdate code